# Rank of the group $\mathbb Z^{n-1}\oplus \mathbb Z_2$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I was solving an exercise from Rotman's An Introduction to Algebraic Topology that I had to study the $2n$-gon $M$, i.e., the polygonom in the plane with edges labed by $\alpha_1,\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n, \alpha_n$, with edges identified. This exercise asks to calculate to show that the rank of $H_1(M)=n-1$, I was able to calculate it using cell-complex structure and got $H_1(M)=\mathbb Z^{n-1}\oplus \mathbb Z_2$, and I can't see how this group has rank $n-1$, because the only generator that I can find is $\langle (1,\dots,[0]),\dots,(0,\dots,[1])\rangle$, and so the rank should be $n$.

Moreover for $n=1$ the $2n$-gon is $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$, and $H_1(\mathbb R\mathbb P^2)=\mathbb Z_2$, and rank $\mathbb Z_2=1$. So it seems to fail even for $n=1$.

Am I right, or am I missing some detail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rank of a f.g abelian group is usually asking for non-torision components. In particular, every abelian group is a  $\mathbb Z$-module, and the rank is the number of its free generators.

Alternatively, the rank could be viewed as $\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb Q (M \otimes_{A} \mathbb Q)$ in the usual sense, which would again agree with this. Here is an [MO post distinguishing these two things](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29993/rank-of-a-module).